# Android Facebook parse login logic called twice

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

So here is the code

```
public void redirectToMain(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pers.clear();
    pers.add("user_friends");
    pers.add("email");

    if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        redirectToMain();
    }

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "user_friends");
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            parseLogin();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });
}

public void parseLogin(){
    loginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, pers, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if(user==null){
                Log.i("Cancel", "facebook");
            }else if(user.isNew()){
                Log.i("Parse", "succcess");
                redirectToMain();
            }
            else{
                Log.i("Parse", "old");
                redirectToMain();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data );
    ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}
```

}

And everything works fine, the user gets redirected to the second activity, but the activity gets called twice. Also, the log part that says old is also written twice in the logcat, so my assumption is that either parseLogin() or the ParseFacebookUtils.log...() is called twice. Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: try removing the `ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);`...

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you!

Comment: i have added it as an answer........

Comment: After more testing I found out this solution doesn't work because parse needs that line for the login. Else it gives an error "can't login while another application is logging out". Please remove your answer.

Comment: @ubuntuaskdanidani Have you found the right solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by adding an int and a while loop that executes the code only once. It's more of a hack than a fix, so maybe somebody can come up with a better solution.